# HTML table needs spacing between columns, not rows

Tags: html

I have an HTML table.
I need to have spacing between the table columns, but not the table rows.

If I use the `cellspacing` CSS property it does it between both rows and columns. I also cannot use CSS in what I doing. I need to use pure HTML.

Comment: Does that leave out inline styling?

Comment: add an extra td with a non-breaking space (&nbsp;) in it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you can use inline styling, you can set the left and right padding on each `td`.. Or you use an extra `td` between columns and set a number of non-breaking spaces as @rene kindly suggested.

http://jsfiddle.net/u5mN4/

http://jsfiddle.net/u5mN4/1/

Both are pretty ugly ;p css ftw

Comment: I recommend inline css, the blank `<td>` will be annoying for people who use assistive technology

Answer (score 68):

The better approach uses Shredder's  css rule: padding: 0 15px 0 15px
only instead of inline css, define a css rule that applies to all tds.
Do This by using a style tag in your page:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  td {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
</style>
```

or give the table a class like "paddingBetweenCols" and in the site css use

```css
.paddingBetweenCols td {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

The site css approach defines a central rule that can be reused by all pages.

If your doing to use the site css approach, it would be best to define a class like above and apply the padding to the class...unless you want all td's on the entire site to have the same rule applied.

[Fiddle for using style tag](http://jsfiddle.net/ordw66Ly/)

[Fiddle for using site css](http://jsfiddle.net/q8dh0uh7/)

Answer (score 13):

```
<table cellpadding="pixels"cellspacing="pixels"></table>
<td align="position"valign="position"></td>
```

`cellpadding`="length in pixels" ~ The cellpadding attribute, used in the `<table>` tag, specifies how much blank space to display in between the content of each table cell and its respective border. The value is defined as a length in pixels. Hence, a `cellpadding="10"` attribute-value pair will display 10 pixels of blank space on all four sides of the content of each cell in that table.

`cellspacing`="length in pixels" ~ The cellspacing attribute, also used in the `<table>` tag, defines how much blank space to display in between adjacent table cells and in between table cells and the table border. The value is defined as a length in pixels. Hence, a `cellspacing="10"` attribute-value pair will horizontally and vertically separate all adjacent cells in the respective table by a length of 10 pixels. It will also offset all cells from the table's frame on all four sides by a length of 10 pixels.

Comment: Note: It also seems to work to use inline CSS on the TABLE tag.  <TABLE STYLE='padding:0px 20px 0px 0px'> provides 20 pixels of padding on the right margin.

Answer (score 9):

In most cases it could be better to pad the columns only on the right so just the spacing between the columns gets padded, and the first column is still aligned with the table.

CSS:

```
.padding-table-columns td
{
    padding:0 5px 0 0; /* Only right padding*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<table className="padding-table-columns">
  <tr>
    <td>Cell one</td>
     <!-- There will be a 5px space here-->
    <td>Cell two</td>
     <!-- There will be an invisible 5px space here-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by putting padding *between* the columns using CSS. You can either add padding to the left of all columns except the first, or add padding to the right of all columns except the last. You should avoid adding padding to the right of the last column or to the left of the first as this will insert redundant white space. You should also avoid being too prescriptive with classes to specify which columns should have the additional padding as this will make maintenance harder if you later add a new column.

The '[lobotomised owl selector](https://css-tricks.com/lobotomized-owls/)' allows you to select all siblings, regardless of if they are a `th`, `td` or something else.

```css
tr > * + * {
  padding-left: 4em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can select all `td` elements except the last one in a more obvious way:

```css
tr > td:not(:last-child) { padding-right: 2em; }
```

or

```css
tr > td:not(:last-child), tr > th:not(:last-child) { padding-right: 2em; }
```

if table headers should also be separated

Answer (score 2):

As of the time of this question, the CSS [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property may not have been widely supported, but now, it is well-supported across modern browsers. You can achieve spacing between table columns without affecting table rows by using the `border-spacing`.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 20px 0;
}

/* some border to see the spacing */
th, td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```