# how to get top whitespace or margin space for a html table for next page if content is going to next page in html

Tags: html, css

I am creating a large html table consists of 3 cols when first page is full ,rest of the table content going to the next page but it is starting at the top of the page and ending at very bottom page I am unable to  get top margin space in second page when content is going to second page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm gettig what you're saying then your html looks something like that:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<-!---if that's the case you could add padding to the third column like that:-->
<style>

table tr td:nth-child(3){
padding: 0.3rem 0
}
</style>
```

***More options that might be helpful-***

[Creating Tables with DIV tags](https://mymoduledesign.com/2021/06/22/creating-tables-with-div-tag/#:%7E:text=Although%20it%20is%20good%20to,data%20using%20DIVs%20with%20CSS.)

[HTML table needs spacing between columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800975/html-table-needs-spacing-between-columns-not-rows)

[CSS gap space with flexbox](https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-gap-space-with-flexbox)